# Google OAuth2 authentication using python-social-auth on Google App Engine failed

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-social-auth

I have an issue with python-social-auth for Google OAuth2 authentication.
I'm developing project using django 1.7 and deploying it to Google App Engine.

I tested login by google using oauth2 with python-social-auth on my local environment(Ubuntu, django1.7, virtualenv, python-social-auth)
Of course, I got API credentials from "API and auth" console.

I deployed project to Google app engine.
If I click "login by google", it redirects to page which requires user to input his password.
After that it shows me error like "AuthFailed at /complete/google-oauth2/
Authentication failed: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))"

Debug message shows me that "request_access_token" generate above issue.

But the point is it works well on local testing without any issue.

Any kind of help would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading *requests* module to 2.3 worked for me:

```
pip uninstall requests        # 2.5.1, then
pip install requests==2.3
```

Thanks to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27986163/4347114)